# Using Java on Ubuntu - Package conflict?

Tags: java, c++, gcc, terminal, package

On linux, I often launch and compile from the command line (java/javac)
Though, Java isn't the only language I use - I use C++, and for that I have GCC. Because I have both java and GCC, for example, there are more than one instance of 'javac':

From the terminal, passing 'javac' with no arguments:

The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.4-jdk
 * gcj-4.5-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install

Is there a way to specify which package I want to use? Either per-command, or set a default? I would prefer not to remove one or the other.

Thanks - 
Zac

Comment: You can try creating an alias, perhaps.

Comment: That's what the alias system does in a uniform way. You can use the technique for x-www-browser, editor, pager and so on. `ls /etc/alternatives/` shows what exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  update-java-alternatives -s openjdk-6-jdk
```

On Ubuntu there is a system called `alternatvies` installed, to switch between different implementations:

```
update-java-alternatives

man update-java-alternatives
```

shows the usage:

```
NAME
       update-java-alternatives - update alternatives for jre/sdk installations

SYNOPSIS
       update-java-alternatives [--jre] [--plugin] [-t|--test|-v|--verbose]
             -l|--list [<jname>]
             -s|--set <jname>
             -a|--auto
             -h|-?|--help
```

If you get problems with swing, you should try sun-java, which you're missing in your list. :)

As 'KindOfAutomatic suggests:

```
alternatives --config java
alternatives --config javac
```

is the same thing in a different way. Instead of 'java', you can config your favorite editor, x-www-browser, pager and so on as well. Have a look at

```
ls /etc/alternatives
```

to get an impression, what's already done there.

Comment: +1 Not every distribution provides `update-java-alternatives`, though. For these, try `alternatives --config java/javac`.

Comment: Solid answer, thanks. Though using the command you posted to use openjdk-6-jdk couldn't find the directory. I'll check the paths.

Comment: I tried to locate each package and 'locate' for each package returned nothing - apparently it wasn't installed. Fixing that now, will give it a shot after it finishes.

Comment: @KindOfAutomatic: Tried to adopt your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: javac without any arguments returns the syntax now - works perfectly. Thanks for the advice, I know I'll be needing to use it at some point.

Comment: With `update-java-alternatives -l` you get a list, what is already recognized and available. Maybe the package is named in a different way.